# Apache Redirect not working for me

Tags: apache, redirect

We have a problem where a piece of software is wanting to open a web page to a server that no longer exists and the replacement server uses a different URL structure.

I've been tasked with implementing a solution to this and have been looking at Apache Redirects.  This is running on a RHEL 7.5 VM using Apache v2.4.6 which is shipped with RHEL.

So far, my config looks like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/wp2/geoviewer-prod/wpc.jsp?latitude=(.*)&longitude=(.*)&scale=(.*)" "http://newserver/server/#/map/$1,$2,19z" [B,PT,NE,R=301,L]
RewriteEngine off
```

In the Apache access_log file I see:

```
192.168.249.30 - - [30/Apr/2018:12:12:07 +0800] "GET /wp2/geoviewer-prod/wpc.jsp?latitude=-2.2&longitude=4.4&scale=3000000 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

The browser never goes to the new server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

EDITED: changed from "code" to "pre" tags and its displaying correctly now.

EDIT2: I've turned Apache logging up to 11 and there is no mention of 'rewrite' in the logs.

Comment: Your regular expression is wrong. The question mark needs to be escaped, `(.)` only denotes one character so it will never match `-2.2` for example. Maybe more errors.

Comment: Apologies, I was using CODE tags and the config was not displaying correctly.  Fixed now.

Comment: Your question mark still needs to be escaped. The best way to make sure your regexp is correct is to test it in a tool like https://regex101.com/ to eliminate any regexp issue before rejecting the fault on apache.

Comment: I escaped the question mark but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualHost context, `RewriteRule` *pattern* will be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, **and before the query string**. 
If you wish to match against the  query string, use a `RewriteCond` with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} latitude=(.*)&longitude=(.*)&scale=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/wp2/geoviewer-prod/wpc.jsp http://newserver/server/#/map/%1,%2,19z [B,PT,NE,R=301,L]
#RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this but still the same behavior.  I should have noted that I had to create /var/www/html//wp2/geoviewer-prod/wpc.jsp to stop 404 errors.  I'm wondering if this is at least part of my problem...